# Using common dialog to save picturebox as image vb6

Tags: vb6

I am using the common dialog control to save a picturebox in my form as an image. However, when I test it out, the bmp file that is produced is blank.

I am using the line function to draw lines on the picutrebox. This is what I want to save.

My code:

```
Private Sub mnuFileSave_Click()

Dim FileName As String

savedlg.FileName = ""
savedlg.Filter = "Bitmap files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|"
savedlg.ShowSave
If savedlg.FileName = "" Then Exit Sub
picGraph.Picture = picGraph.Image
SavePicture picGraph.Picture, savedlg.FileName

End Sub
```

Any help as to why the saved bmp file is coming up blank would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: I have also found that the picture box goes blank when the picture is saved as an image.

Comment: No. Tried installing it now but it says "did not install successfully".

Comment: Did you "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Yes. I am running it on windows 10, could that be an issue?

Comment: You might want to look at this http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?820079-RESOLVED-SP6-Windows-10-Fails-to-Install

Comment: found the solution, thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is simple:

AutoRedraw on the picture box must be set to true. It was set to false before.